# JPQL with specific column returning Object array

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have repository method where i am trying to fetch specific column from table. 
when i call findAllNamesAndID method i get Object array in return where i am expecting List of Customwidgets.

I am not sure whats wrong with below code.

I can use use constructor of Customwidgets in query annotation but i want to avoid that. Is there any workaround.

I have below domain class :-

```
public class Customwidgets implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

---
---
}
```

My Repository class :-

```
@Repository
public interface CustomwidgetsRepository extends JpaRepository<Customwidgets, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customwidgets> {

    @Query("select o.id, o.name from Customwidgets o")
    List<Customwidgets> findAllNamesAndID();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface to define your projection. For instance:

```
public interface CustomWidgetsProjection {

   String getId();

   String getName();

}
```

Then you can return this interface you created instead of `CustomWidgets`:

```
@Query("select o.id, o.name from Customwidgets o")
List<CustomWidgetsProjection> findAllNamesAndID();
```